# c# Loading of serialized file fails - Class property i:type

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, win-universal-app, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to program a home automation Software. At the moment I have the following classes:

-Home
-Room
-Device
-WindowShutter (Inherits from Device)
-Sensor (Inherits from Device)

Currently the Home Object, which contains Rooms (which contains devices) is saved in XML.

```
public static async void SaveHome(Home MyHome)
        {
            MemoryStream _MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractSerializer Serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Home));
            Serializer.WriteObject(_MemoryStream, MyHome);

            StorageFile _File = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Home2.bin", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            using (Stream fileStream = await _File.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                _MemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await _MemoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                await fileStream.FlushAsync();
                fileStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Because of the different device types, the saved file Looks like this:

```
<Home xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CSRedAlert.Core.Classes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Name>My Home</Name>
<Rooms>
<Room><Color/><Devices><Device><I2C_Slave_Address>64</I2C_Slave_Address><Id>0</Id><ImagePath i:nil="true"/><Name>My Device</Name><Pin>D0</Pin></Device>
<Device i:type="WindowShutter"><I2C_Slave_Address>64</I2C_Slave_Address><Id>1</Id><ImagePath i:nil="true"/><Name>My Window Shutter</Name><Pin>D0</Pin><SecondaryPin>D1</SecondaryPin></Device>
<Device i:type="Sensor"><I2C_Slave_Address>64</I2C_Slave_Address><Id>2</Id><ImagePath i:nil="true"/><Name>My Sensor</Name><Pin>A2</Pin></Device></Devices><I2C_SlaveAdress>64</I2C_SlaveAdress>
<Name>Room</Name></Room></Rooms></Home>
```

The Problem is, as soon as I start the program a second time and the Home2.bin file is loaded, I get the following error:

[Aggregate Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U56v.png)

This is the Method, which loads the File:

```
public static async Task<Home> LoadHome()
        {
            StorageFolder _Folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile _File;

            try
            {
                _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync("Home2.bin");

                Stream stream = await _File.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

                DataContractSerializer Serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Home));

                return (Home)Serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                return new Home();
            }
        }
```

I figured out, that the file will be loaded when I delete the i:type property from the device Elements within the Home2.bin file. But when I delete it, the devices will loose their type and won't work as expected.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: New to see the definition of the classes.  The pseudo ops statements above the definition of the classes and properties need ti be defined properly so both the serialize and de-serialize will both work.  Make sure if you are tow applications (one for serialize and other for de-serialize) that both get updated when changes are made to the classes.

Comment: When you get an AggregateException, the first thing you need to do is checking the [InnerException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing that exception is that [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires that all types that it encounters during serialization be statically discoverable *in advance* via reflection.  If it encounters an unexpected type -- including a subclass of a polymorphic type -- it throws an exception.

For polymorphic types, you can inform the serializer of expected subtypes using [`[KnownTypeAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Once that is done, the [`"{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) attribute will indicate the name of the actual contract that got serialized.

Thus your classes should look something like:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CSRedAlert.Core.Classes")]
[KnownType(typeof(WindowShutter))]
[KnownType(typeof(Sensor))]
public class Device
{
    [DataMember]
    public int I2C_Slave_Address { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Pin { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CSRedAlert.Core.Classes")]
public class WindowShutter : Device
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SecondaryPin { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CSRedAlert.Core.Classes")]
public class Sensor : Device
{
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CSRedAlert.Core.Classes")]
public class Home
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CSRedAlert.Core.Classes")]
public class Room
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int I2C_SlaveAdress { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For more, see [Data Contract Known Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Known Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751512%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! I changed the Code and it works now: Again, thank you!